# How to mask email address in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, email

I need the result for the below mentioned requirement.

```
SELECT substr('name@address.com', 0, instr('name@address.com', '@')-1) 
FROM dual;
```

I can take the sub string from the email address before '@' from the above query:

> 'name'

but I need to make this for different email address that may vary in length.

I need output like this

> xxme@address.com or naxx@address.com

Please help me on this, thank you

Comment: give some sample input and output as an example. because your query works fine in case of any length before @ symbol

Comment: What is the algorithm you want to use to mask the data?  Do you want to replace the first 2 characters with x's?  The last 2 characters?  The first half of the name?  The last half of the name?  If you want to do something based on halves, what if the length is not even?  What if there is only 1 character before the @?

Comment: Why would you do this in Oracle? A SQL database is a data persistence system. Use a general purpose programing to do this at the client interface or UI level. You are making a mess or a system for yourself, or the next programmer to fix! You will probably find this question already answered for most common languages OTHER than SQL

Comment: Why not just settle with something like `SELECT 'xxxx' || substr('name@address.com', (instr('name@address.com', '@') -2)) 
  FROM dual;` ? Why is the need to show length of masked email?

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions, you can do this:

```
with w as
(
    SELECT 'name@address.com' mail from dual
    union all
    SELECT 'xxme@address.com' mail from dual
    union all
    SELECT 'naxx@address.com' mail from dual
)
select regexp_replace(w.mail, '(\w+)@.*', '\1') replaced
from w;
```

My matching is not perfect, but this is a good start !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE('name@address.com',substr('name@address.com', instr('name@address.com', '@')-2,2),'**')  
  FROM dual;
```

it is working perfect..

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what your looking for :

```
WITH CTE AS
( 
  SELECT 'xyz@gmail.com' as addr from dual
  union
  select 'abcdef@yahoo.com' as addr from dual
)
select substr(addr,1,instr(addr,'@',1,1)-1) as name from cte;
```

This will return xyz and abcdef.